# mongo efficient remove data from big collection

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a big collection of millions entries.  I want to remove efficiently all the data, but without dropping the collection.

What is the best way to do that?

```
db.some_coll.remove({})
```

takes a lot of time!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to do that?

You have found it. There are only two ways to clear out a collection:

1. `db.some_coll.remove({})`: which deletes everything one at a time. It takes a long time because each deletion is as expensive as an insert.
2. `db.some_coll.drop()`: simply clears the entire collection.

> I want to remove efficiently all the entire data, but without dropping the collection.

Why not drop the collection? You want to remove all of the data, all you need to do is re-create the indexes and possibly the settings on the collection (*capped collections only*).

Re-creating indexes is *very* easy. **So what's the hangup**?

Comment: I have also sharding. If I use drop I have to reconfigure it to be shared collection. How can I do this transparently to application?

Comment: Sharding a collection is similar to re-creating an index, except that you will lose the data in the config DB with respect to your chunks. You will have to define *"transparent to application"*? You are deleting a bunch of data, the application is going to notice.

Comment: Yes of course. My business logic is delete data and insert a new data. I am aware that there is a period of time that the data is not consistently full. But I want the sharing configuration be transparent to my application server

Comment: Hold on, your business logic is removing all of the data? You mean, you plan to delete all of your data from a sharded collection on a regular basis?

Comment: If I get each time all the data as input, i can treat it in two ways : update the data each document one by with upsert or recreate the data with bulk insert. I think that the second is much more efficient isn't it?

Comment: Bulk insert in MongoDB != bulk insert in SQL. In MongoDB *all* inserts can accept more than one document at a time, so "bulk insert" in MongoDB is just a regular insert where you send multiple documents at once. So it's faster, but not 10x faster. Given that you cannot drop the collection (you want to keep your data sharded), you'll have to resort to doing a bunch of upserts. I would suggest breaking up the data among several workers for more simultaneous upserts.